# What is the difference between ～あろうが and ～あろうと?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, meaning

I'm writing a report for a class, and at first I wrote:

> ［…］どのような批判があろう**が**［…］

But then I sat back and thought, maybe it should actually be:

> ［…］どのような批判があろう**と**［…］

But now I'm not sure if there's actually a difference, or if there is, how it actually affects the meaning in this case. So... **do these actually have different meanings/connotations?** And if so, how so?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 論文とか、正式な文章なら、「～～あろうが(なかろうが)」よりも「～～あろうと(なかろうと)」「～～あろうと(も)」のほうがいいかなと思います。文語的だからかな？私だけかもしれないけど。

Comment: @Choko ありがとうございます！回答でお願いしてもよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is virtually no difference in meaning but there is a slight difference in nuance, therefore, in actual usage.

Using 「どのような批判があろう + が」 could make you sound a bit more defensive and/or excited about your own opinion being presented than when using 「どのような批判があろう + と」.  The latter would help show your composure as an author better than the former.

Without knowing what you want to say in your report, however, it is difficult to say which one you should choose.  The "safer" choice in general would be to use 「と」, naturally.

Comment: Yes, I think と is the correct choice in my particular case. Thanks!